# IBM Content Navigator grid issues

Tags: ibm-content-navigator

I have written a custom feature for ICN which has dojo tree grid and enhanced grids. But for some reason, CSS on both grids are not looking good i.e grid headers are not aligned with the column. I have attached a few prints shots highlighting the problem. Please help me to solve this. If run these outside of ICN, I see everything working fine. Even sorting of the grids are also not working as expected within ICN.
[Enhanced grid css issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzk5D.png)

[Another one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxU9A.png)

Comment: are you using the same dojo version that ICN uses?  I've noticed in FileNet ACCE, which uses ICN, that all the grids have misalignment issues.

Comment: @Christopher Powell, Yes i'm using the same dojo version. Also one interesting thing that I noticed is that, in ICN, they are not using dojo grids rather they use contentlist grid which is a customized version of dojo grid and they apply their own css. Now i'm trying to follow the same approach. Have you ever used ContentList? If so can you share some sample code please?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...  We try to extend the js classes that ICN provides, and then override any methods where change is needed.  That allows ICN to build the contentlist's for us.  This leads to some problems, but in general keeps our coding to a minimum. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837170/altering-the-check-in-dialogue-in-icn-ibm-content-navigator?rq=1) to see an example of how to override the checkin dialog.  You could use the same example to override a contentlist pane.

Comment: @Christopher Powell, thanks for that link that was informative. I tried couple of things i.e. to override the css for dojo enhance grid but in vain. Now I started using ContentList grid which comes with ICN and rendering the results using it. That seems to work.

Comment: I'll write up an answer for this shortly, but I don't think it really answers your question.  It just provides a potential workaround.  Glad to hear its working for you.